# Unwind resume error when building code including chilkat library

Tags: codeblocks, chilkat, chilkat-email

I'm trying to add the Chilkat C/C++ libraries into a project in CodeBlocks (32-bit, version 12.11) for Windows 7.

So I went to http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_mingw.asp, and downloaded the 32-bit MinGW library.

Then in CodeBlocks I did:

1. Settings>Compiler>Linker Settings>Add>C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a
2. Settings>Compiler>Search Directories>Compiler>Add>C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\include
3. Settings>Compiler>Search Directories>Linker>Add>C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32
4. Project>Build Options...>Project Root>Linker Settings>Add>C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a
5. Project>Build Options...>Project Root>Search Directory>Compiler>Add>C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\include
6. Project>Build Options...>Project Root>Search Directory>Linker>Add>C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32
7. Then I set my compiler to GNU GCC Compiler.

Finally, I encounter these two issues:

1. When I do `#include<...>` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> inside the brackets, there are no suggestions for anything related to the Chilkat library. See first code block below for full code (pretty simple).
2. While the program builds successfully with `CkMailMan.h` included, it breaks when I instantiate `CkMailMan`, with the errors shown in the second code block below.

I suspect it has to do with the library extension being ".a," which is for Linux. **But I get the same problem when I do a Visual Basic version of this library (extensions .dll) and use the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 compiler.** Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CkMailMan.h>
using namespace std;

CkMailMan mailman;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Error messages in Build Log when running code:**

```
-------------- Build: Debug in TimeButler (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g    -IC:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\include -IC:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\include -IC:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\include  -c C:\TimeButler\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs -LC:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32 -LC:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32  -o bin\Debug\TimeButler.exe obj\Debug\main.o    C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatDbg.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatDbgDll.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatRel.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatRelDll.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatDbg.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatDbgDll.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatRel.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc10\libs\ChilkatRelDll.lib C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a 
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMailMan.o):CkMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMailMan.o):CkMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMailMan.o):CkMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x395): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMailMan.o):CkMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x4cf): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMailMan.o):CkMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x5d7): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMailMan.o):CkMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x6df): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMailMan.o):CkMailMan.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsBase.o):ClsBase.cpp:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsBase.o):ClsBase.cpp:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsBase.o):ClsBase.cpp:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsBase.o):ClsBase.cpp:(.text+0x35b): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsBase.o):ClsBase.cpp:(.text+0x805): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsBase.o):ClsBase.cpp:(.text+0x9c8): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsBase.o):ClsBase.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x173): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMultiByteBase.o):CkMultiByteBase.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMultiByteBase.o):CkMultiByteBase.cpp:(.text+0x522): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMultiByteBase.o):CkMultiByteBase.cpp:(.text+0x666): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkMultiByteBase.o):CkMultiByteBase.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsMailMan.o):ClsMailMan.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsMailMan.o):ClsMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsMailMan.o):ClsMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x3fd): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsMailMan.o):ClsMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x587): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsMailMan.o):ClsMailMan.cpp:(.text+0x8af): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsMailMan.o):ClsMailMan.cpp:(.text+0xbd3): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsMailMan.o):ClsMailMan.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x3f): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(_clsTcp.o):_clsTcp.cpp:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(_clsTcp.o):_clsTcp.cpp:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(_clsTcp.o):_clsTcp.cpp:(.text+0x3bf): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(_clsTcp.o):_clsTcp.cpp:(.text+0x5ff): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(_clsTcp.o):_clsTcp.cpp:(.text+0x806): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(_clsTcp.o):_clsTcp.cpp:(.text+0x88b): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(_clsTcp.o):_clsTcp.cpp:(.eh_frame+0xcb): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkString.o):CkString.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkString.o):CkString.cpp:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkString.o):CkString.cpp:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkString.o):CkString.cpp:(.text+0x3dd): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkString.o):CkString.cpp:(.text+0x451): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkString.o):CkString.cpp:(.text+0x4e2): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(CkString.o):CkString.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(XString.o):XString.cpp:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(XString.o):XString.cpp:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(XString.o):XString.cpp:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(XString.o):XString.cpp:(.text+0x862): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(XString.o):XString.cpp:(.text+0xfd9): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(XString.o):XString.cpp:(.text+0xff3): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(XString.o):XString.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsHttpProxyClient.o):ClsHttpProxyClient.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsHttpProxyClient.o):ClsHttpProxyClient.cpp:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsHttpProxyClient.o):ClsHttpProxyClient.cpp:(.text+0x482): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-mingw32\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ClsHttpProxyClient.o):ClsHttpProxyClient.cpp:(.text+0x733): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 10 seconds)
50 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 10 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to switch to the visual Studio C++ compiler and download the library in that compiler's format. I was right about not being able to use '.a' extension libraries.